# Layout results in all white content

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Why are all my content white? When I use code to update a string it shows correctly, but nothing shows correctly until then. It looks fine in android studio design view.

[All white buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBip1.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tomasforsman.snookerscore.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textP1Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/player1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textP2Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/player2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageP1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/player1_img_desc"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textP1Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textP1Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textP1Name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/male_user" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageP2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/player2_img_desc"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textP2Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textP2Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textP2Name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/male_user" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBlue"
        tools:text="@string/pink" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonPink"
        tools:text="@string/red" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonRed"
        tools:text="@string/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonYellow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBrown"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonBrown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonBrown"
        tools:text="@string/yello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonBlue"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageP1"
        tools:text="@string/brown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBrown"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonBrown"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonBrown"
        tools:text="@string/green" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textP1ScoreTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textP2ScoreTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textP1Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textP2ScoreTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textP2Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textP1ScoreTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textP1Score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textP1ScoreTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textP1ScoreTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textP1ScoreTitle"
        tools:text="@string/text_p1_score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textP2Score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textP2ScoreTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textP2ScoreTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textP2ScoreTitle"
        tools:text="@string/text_p2_score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBreakTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBlue"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonBlue"
        tools:text="@string/break_score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBreak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textBreakTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/text_break" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLeftOnTableTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonPink"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBlue"
        tools:text="@string/left_on_table" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLeftOnTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textLeftOnTableTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textLeftOnTableTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textLeftOnTableTitle"
        tools:text="@string/text_left_on_table" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRedOnTableTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonRed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonRed"
        tools:text="@string/red_on_table" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRedOnTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textRedOnTableTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textRedOnTableTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textRedOnTableTitle"
        tools:text="15" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried to clean the code and rebuild it and tried with fresh projects in different versions of android studio. I'm sure I miss something easy but can't figure out what.

The strings xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Snooker Score</string>
    <string name="red">Red</string>
    <string name="black">Black</string>
    <string name="pink">Pink</string>
    <string name="blue">Blue</string>
    <string name="yello">Yellow</string>
    <string name="brown">Brown</string>
    <string name="green">Green</string>
    <string name="score">Score</string>
    <string name="break_score">Break:</string>
    <string name="left_on_table">Left on table:</string>
    <string name="red_on_table">Red on table:</string>
    <string name="player1">Player 1</string>
    <string name="player2">Player 2</string>
    <string name="player1_img_desc">Player 1 description.</string>
    <string name="player2_img_desc">Player 2 description.</string>
    <string name="text_p1_score">155</string>
    <string name="text_p2_score">155</string>
    <string name="text_break">155</string>
    <string name="text_left_on_table">155</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use:**

```
android:text="@string/your_string_name"
```

**DO NOT USE**:

```
tools:text="@string/your_string_name"
```

Comment: And that's why you should do everything in XML and not rely on the designer, unless you know what all the fields are doing at least. Using the wrong text field results in using tools. 

Now I've learned that tools are for the design view only.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I am glad you solved the problem **Happy Coding!**.

Answer (score 0):

All XML attributes with `tools:` are removed from the XML when it runs on the device.

You're using the wrong attributes

Also, you mention "white content"... I don't see how putting text will change the color of a button. That's just what's written on it.

I think you want to either use an ImageButton or set the background, not text